# Using a FileReader in Java to get a String from a specific location in a file

Tags: java, filereader

I am trying to figure out how to setup a FileReader wrapped in a BufferedReader so that I can grab a specific string value from different parts of the file.

Example: The file will contain content similar to this.

First Name: John
Last Name: Doe

My FileWriter is creating the file correctly and saving it line by line like the example above.  I am now trying to save the value of the names from the file through the reader.

```
public void reader() {

    String fileName = "C:/Users/computerUser/Desktop/output.txt";
    String line = null;
    String fileContent = null;

    try {
        FileReader in = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(in);
        while((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileContent = fileContent + line;
        }   

        //substring of 4 is used to ignore the initial string value of null.
        fileContent = fileContent.substring(4);
        bufferReader.close();

        System.out.println(fileContent);

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("File is blank");
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)), "UTF-8"));` instead of `FileReader in = new FileReader(fileName);` because `FileReader` uses platform encoding and may result in inconsistency on platform change.

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: @dinomario10 `BufferedReader` decorating a `BufferedInputStream`? No. Double buffering should be avoided.

Comment: You need to actually ask a question and explain what isn't going as expected.

Comment: Don't concatenate all the lines. Read the file line by line. For each line, split on `:`. The key is the first element, the value is the second element.

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet 100%. Compilers can process program files a characater at a time, so there is almost certainly no reason why you need to read the entire file into memory. However, if you must, initialize the string to `""`, not null, to avoid the final `substring()` call. Better still, accumulate the data in a `StringBuilder`, which you will find many times as fast, instead of a `String`. But I see no actual question here.